Azure Pipeline generate Swagger for ASP.NET Core Web API
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that I build in Azure Devops. I have to extract the swagger during the build.
I therefore issue the following command:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Generate Swagger'
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet new tool-manifest
      dotnet tool install --version 6.5.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
      cd Api
      set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      dotnet swagger tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Api/bin/Release/net8.0/Api.dll  v1
  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'

The problem is that I have the impression that it launches the application because it looks for my appsettings.json and once filled, it tries to connect to the BDD.
How do I generate my Swagger in CI?
Load appsettings.json file in Main method :
IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();


I've never used that tool before, but if you need to load the right appsettings.json file based on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable try using the env property, which is the recommended way to set environment variables for tasks.
This method works across different types of agents (Windows, Linux, macOS), ensuring that your pipeline behaves consistently regardless of the agent type.
Try:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Generate Swagger'
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet new tool-manifest
      dotnet tool install --version 6.5.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
      cd Api
      dotnet swagger tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Api/bin/Release/net8.0/Api.dll  v1
  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
  env:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Development'

Instead of:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Generate Swagger'
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet new tool-manifest
      dotnet tool install --version 6.5.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
      cd Api
      set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      dotnet swagger tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Api/bin/Release/net8.0/Api.dll  v1
  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'

See Environment variables

The problem is more loading the appsettings file. It loads it well there. The trouble is that it tries to connect to the database out in the here I don’t want. How to ignore this step when you are in a here
